# Error using unordered_set_of with Boost.Bimap

Tags: c++, boost, bimap, boost-bimap

I'm attempting to follow [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/example/repetitions_counter.cpp) from the documentation (see typedef for word_counter).

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/unordered_set_of.hpp>

typedef boost::bimap
<
  boost::bimap::unordered_set_of< std::string >,
  std::string
> MyBimap;
```

Error thrown is

> test.cpp:11:1: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 5)
>   In file included from /usr/include/boost/bimap.hpp:13:0, from test.cpp:3:
>   /usr/include/boost/bimap/bimap.hpp:133:7: error: provided for ‘template class boost::bimaps::bimap’
>   test.cpp:11:10: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token

Comment: What compiler and version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo.
Instead of

```
boost::bimap::unordered_set_of< std::string >,
```

use

```
boost::bimaps::unordered_set_of< std::string >,
```

in the template.

It will compile then.